# Ag-Grid - add filter to a cell's right-click context menu

Tags: filter, ag-grid

Is there a way to right-click on a cell and choose 'Filter by'? Ideally, it could be added to the contextual menu.

[image: Add Filter By to context menu]

Answer (score 0):

You are able to achieve it by customising [`contextMenu`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/) via `getContextMenuItems` property.

Just a brief example:

```
function myOwnContextMenuItems(params) {
    const menuItems = [
    {
      // custom item
      // params.value here is a cell value (country name in your case)
      name: 'Filter by ' + params.value, 
      action: () => {
        // call sorting function here (also via params.api or even custom-one)
      },
    },
}

const gridOptions = {
    ...,
    getContextMenuItems: myOwnContextMenuItems,
}
```

> Preventing the question (Am I suppose to add manually all 'default' menu-items?)
>
> - yes if you need, custom menu logic is an override and you are able to add/remove [default build in items](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/#built-in-menu-items) or implement custom.

PS: context menu - is a kinda cell-wrapper, and when you right click on other cell (other column, not country) `params.value` would be different.

PSS: for sure you are able to handle it by **conditionally adding** 'filter by' menu item **only when** column is 'country', to identify the column you have to deeply explore the `params` cuz it does contain pretty much all required data for it.

UPDATE: 01.2024

As i've tried to explain it is possible to get access to almost everything via `params`:

`node` via `params.node`

`columnApi` via `params.columnApi`

`column` (structure) via `params.column`

or directly root API via `params.api`

[image]

Comment: any ideas how i can identify the cell with out checking the value? is there something like the index position?

Comment: @norca updated an answer